# Personal Hotspot question

Tags: ios, cellular-data, tethering, cellular-carriers

So I have an iPhone that's connected to wifi. I forgot the Wifi password and want to connect a device to my phones personal hotspot, does it cost extra money if I do?

Answer (score 1):

That depends on your service provider. In the US if you use T-mobile with an unlimited plan the answer would be no.

If you pay for data the answer would be yes. The hotspot on your phone is set up to use your mobile data.

One way or another, you pay for tethered data based on what service provider you choose and what plan you choose.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you use USB-Tethering for the connection between your iPhone and the other device, there is no way to start your mobile hotspot as long as you are connected to the WiFi. If you try to, your phone will automatically disconnect from the WiFi.

That is because your phone has only one WiFi card/module on the hardware side, and thus can only manage one WiFi network at a time.

When you connect your phone to a stationary WiFi network, you configure the WiFi module to be the receiving end of the connection (although it of course also sends data).

When you start the hotspot, your phone configures the WiFi module to be the broadcasting end of a WiFi network (although it of course also receives data), exactly like your normal WiFi router at home is, just with a weaker signal.

These two modes cannot operate at the same time.